# How does one include external scripts in a React web application?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have created a React web application using create-react-app and I am busy incorporating a dashboard template into the project. I have managed to build out most of the HTML into various different re-usable React components and I was able to import all the stylesheets successfully. I however hit a brick wall when I tried to incorporate the template's JavaScript files into my project.

So, what I did was I took all the necessary JavaScript files and added them all to a sub-folder of **assets** (located in the **public** folder) called **js**, i.e:

`/public/assets/js/{file.js}`

I then added script tags to the **index.html** in the **public** folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="js">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <!-- other meta tags -->
      <title>My Dashboard</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script type="text/JavaScript" src="./assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
      <script type="text/JavaScript" src="./assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I fire up the development server the app loads properly, however something strange happens with the scripts;
I have added a component (a slider) to the landing page which makes use of the **bundle.js** and **scripts.js** files. When the page initially loads the component displays correctly (i.e. the JS works), however a second later the component becomes completely broken - almost as if the page is refreshed without the JS loading properly the second time round.

When I looked at the console I saw I had two JS files with the same name called up. I realized as part of the *packaging* WebPack does in the background it generates its own bundle and serves it up - and this bundle is also called bundle.js. Consequently I renamed the external JavaScript file to **externalbundle.js** and also respectively made the change to the src attribute in the script tag:

`<script type="text/JavaScript" src="./assets/js/externalbundle.js"></script>`

The app compiles and loads successfully, and I see no warnings or errors in the console, yet the same still happens; the slider loads properly for that first second and then breaks (the console still doesn't show any warnings or errors).

I have also added `console.log('Loaded')` at the end of the **externalbundle.js** file and this appears as expected in the console when the app has loaded.

So I would really like to know if I am referencing these external scripts incorrectly, maybe not fully grasping the way the DOM works and how it deals with external scripts, or is there an entirely different way of dealing with external scripts?

Maybe worth mentioning also is that the JavaScript files that I'm referencing aren't available as libraries on npm. I have also tried importing them inside of index.js instead (of course moving the files to the src directory) which produces all sorts of errors such as

> 'define' is not defined

and

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Trying to convert the existing JS file into a NodeJS "compatible" file (by adding `exports.{filename} = function(a,b) { ... }` and calling it inside of **index.js** by importing `import { filename } from './path/to/file.js'` and calling it using `filename()`) produced even worse results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scriptjs`

```
import $script from 'scriptjs';

class TaskLists extends Component  {

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount () {
    $script(['https://YOUR_SCRIPT_URL_HERE'], 'scriptidentifier');
  }
  render () {
   return (<div>Hello</div>)
  }
}
```

Example from docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs

```
// load jquery and plugin at the same time. name it 'bundle'
$script(['jquery.js', 'my-jquery-plugin.js'], 'bundle')

// load your usage
$script('my-app-that-uses-plugin.js')


/*--- in my-jquery-plugin.js ---*/
$script.ready('bundle', function() {
  // jquery & plugin (this file) are both ready
  // plugin code...
})


/*--- in my-app-that-uses-plugin.js ---*/
$script.ready('bundle', function() {
  // use your plugin :)
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Ayushya, I am trying to implement it as we speak. When I load the app now the slider seems to be broken from the get go. In the Inspector I now see an **event** badge next to the script tag (so at least the script tag was created). When I click on the **event** badge a tooltip opens indicating that an error was triggered. Whether the error is internal to scriptjs or due to something that I've done I'm not sure yet.

Comment: To be sure of it, you can point it out a different JS file which has just an `alert('Hello')`.

I use scriptjs to load some of the third party libraries on demand, it works well for me.

Comment: Got it to work thanks @Ayushya. I tried loading in a script with only `alert('Hello')` which then executed as expected. Turned out there was something inside of the actual JS which prevented the script from loading properly. script.js works well.

Comment: Good to know that it helped. Cheers :P